# Python Sockets: Enabling Promiscuous Mode in Linux

Tags: python, sockets, networking

We know that Python Allows enabling promiscuous mode under Windows through

```
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

However, The RCVALL_* and SIO_* is only available in windows. 
Using C socket api, in Linux, one can use :

```
ethreq.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ethreq);
```

or through,

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, PACKET_MR_PROMISC)
```

Is there any option in **python socket API that allows us to set promiscuous mode in Linux**?

Comment: You need root permissions on Linux in order to use promiscuous mode.

Comment: I had root permissions but thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an `AF_NETLINK` socket to issue a request to turn on `IFF_PROMISC`.  Python can construct `AF_NETLINK` sockets on Linux:

```
>>> from socket import AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, socket 
>>> s = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>>
```

See the example at the end of the netlink(7) manual page for an example of how to issue a netlink request.  You can use `ctypes` (or even `struct`) to construct the serialized nlmsghdr  message to send over the netlink socket.  You may also need it to call `sendmsg` and `recvmsg`, since [Python still doesn't expose these APIs](http://bugs.python.org/issue6560).  Alternatively, there are some [third-party modules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sendmsg) available which expose these two APIs.

Alternatively, you can go the old school route of using `ioctl`, which sadly turns out to be rather simpler.

First define the ifreq structure using ctypes:

```
import ctypes

class ifreq(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ifr_ifrn", ctypes.c_char * 16),
                ("ifr_flags", ctypes.c_short)]
```

Then make a socket to use with the `ioctl` call:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Then copy a couple constant values out of /usr/include since they're not exposed by Python:

```
IFF_PROMISC = 0x100
SIOCGIFFLAGS = 0x8913
SIOCSIFFLAGS = 0x8914
```

Create an instance of the ifreq struct and populate it to have the desired effect:

```
ifr = ifreq()
ifr.ifr_ifrn = "eth4"
```

Populate the `ifr_flags` field with an `ioctl` call so that you don't clobber whatever flags are already set on the interface:

```
import fcntl

fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCGIFFLAGS, ifr) # G for Get
```

Add the promiscuous flag:

```
ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC
```

And set the flags on the interface:

```
fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCSIFFLAGS, ifr) # S for Set
```

To remove the flag, mask it off and set again:

```
ifr.ifr_flags &= ~IFF_PROMISC
fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), SIOCSIFFLAGS, ifr)
```

Comment: Cheers for the detailed answer and providing useful snippets of code.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way I thought of. Maybe not as elegant but seems to work fine.

In linux (with root permissions), one can use :

```
# ifconfig eth0 promisc
# ifconfig eth0 -promisc
```

To enable/ disable promisc mode on your interface (eth0 in this case).

So, in python (with root permissions) one could use :

```
import os
ret =  os.system("ifconfig eth0 promisc")
if ret == 0:
     <Do something>
```

Comments are welcome on this way of doing it.

Comment: A similar approach using the newer "ip" utility would be to run "ip link set eth0 promisc on".  Calling ifconfig in a subprocess is probably going to do the same ioctls as I gave on my answer.  And calling ip in a subprocess is going to do the AF_NETLINK stuff I alluded to but didn't actually spell out (because it's harder :).