# Reading and processing packets from network interface with python

Tags: python, networking, macos-sierra, tunnel, network-interface

So I’m trying to create a tunneling protocol in python. I have the tun interface setup, routed all the traffic through it. 
But now how do I get the packets that are being redirect to the tun interface in my program to encrypt them and send them to the server?
From what I’ve seen it’s either is the socket.bind() or socket.setsockopt() function.
This is my interface setup

[image]

And this the code that i use for now:

```python
import os, sys
from select import select


f = os.open("/dev/tun0", os.O_RDWR)
os.system("ifconfig tun0 add 10.6.0.1 10.6.0.2")
os.system("ip route add 0/1 dev tun0")
try:
    while 1:
        r = select([f],[],[])[0][0]
        if r == f:
            packet = os.read(f, 4000)
            print(str(len(packet)) + " : " + str(packet))


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Stopped by user.")
    os.system("ip route delete 0/1 dev tun0")
```

this directly reads from the device. so is there a way to use the socket library to read packet individually?

Thanks.

OS: macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the tun interface into promiscuous mode so that I can listen for every packet that passes through.

Good start on how to do it is presented in the following SO post:

[Python Sockets: Enabling Promiscuous Mode in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067405/python-sockets-enabling-promiscuous-mode-in-linux)

Other option would be a low-level access to a network interface¸ or your virtual network card driver written in Python.

Comment: Promiscuous mode is maybe not the way to go, my tun0 interface is setup a point to point, take another look at my question i added details

Comment: Why not? With a socket in promiscuous mode and s.readfrom() you get a packet and from whom it came. You would have to have two sniffers, one catching TCP and one catching UDP,  but what does it matter. You can even use asyncore to help you with efficiency.But OK, you chose low-level. I expect you will have to know how to read packet headers manually, i.e. you will need TCP & UDP specs and additional device protocol. Then use struct module to extract metadata and content. But first I advise you to go see how OpenVPN does the trick.

Comment: for the struct use thenewboston has a very good guide on it. if the struct version doesn't work, i'll use the promisc mode. thanks :-)

Comment: I don’t plane to use promisc mode, but how can I do it on Mac OS without using tcpdump?

Comment: Probably using socket.socket.setsockopt() and some help from fcntl module. Also, there is a possibility that pyobjc exposes some easy way to request promiscuous mode. You should check. Also, perhaps reading and writing binary data directly from and to network iface is also implemented in Objective C and with unpacking and all. If there is pyobjc should let you get to it. And spare you time you would spend learning TCP and UDP headers and God knows what else.

Comment: Did you examine OpenVPN code? There they do it quite effectively. Perhaps that part is even in separate file that you can compile as a dynlib and use through ctypes. There might exist a Python module that already does the stuff you require. Did you search for it? On PyPI, github, sourceforge...

Comment: Going through the OpenVPN source is very long and tedious work. So I look into the ioctl and fnctl first, to modify the interface flags. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: When you succeed please post your code here as an answer. I would like to see how you solved your problem.

Comment: @Patrickinc did you happen to write any code?